# Programatically unchecking ng-checkbox in AngularJS on removal from array

Tags: javascript, angularjs, checkbox

I am using a number of checkboxes to push their values to an array to be used as arguments for the filtering of a dataset.

The requirement is to:

1. Show child filters on selection of the parent category.
2. If parent is unchecked all its children should be unchecked (false) automatically (otherwise they will be hidden and still true)
3. Display active filters
4. remove active filter on click (also uncheck their corresponding checkbox programatically).
5. Clear all filters and uncheck all checkboxes.

My current code is below, however see attached fiddle.

```
$scope.IsChecked = false;
$scope.ActiveFilters = [];

$scope.clearFilters = function() {
    $scope.ActiveFilters = [];
};

$scope.ModifyFilter = function (IsChecked, Filter) {
    console.log(IsChecked);
  if (IsChecked) {
    $scope.ActiveFilters.push(Filter);
  }
  else {
    var indexz = $scope.ActiveFilters.indexOf(Filter);
    $scope.ActiveFilters.splice(indexz, 1);
  }
};
```

A fiddle with a semi-working demonstration is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/z5sba90g/4/)

-- EDIT --

Further explanation: When a checkbox is checked it pushed its value to the array. if I remove this from the array by clicking on its name in the 'Active Filters' section at the bottom of the fiddle then it does not uncheck the checkbox. Neither does clicking on 'Clear Filters'.

Comment: Can't understand what the problem...

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in your html bindings. so please post this code here.
You using for "IsChecked" variable. This is local scope variable created for each iteration of loop. You not change it from your script code.

Updated html:

```
<body ng-app="DemoApp" ng-controller="DashboardCtrl"> 

    <div ng-repeat="group in Filters">

       <input type="checkbox" value="{{group.title}}" ng-model="CheckboxParent" />
           {{group.title}}

       <div ng-show="CheckboxParent" class="animate-show" ng-repeat="filter in group.filters">

           <input type="checkbox" class="filterChild" value="{{filter.name}}" ng-model="filter.checked" ng-change="ModifyFilter(filter.checked,filter)"/>
                {{filter.name}} 
       </div>
    </div>

    <div>
      <h4>Active Filters</h4>

        <p class="clear-filters" ng-click="clearFilters()">Clear Filters</p>
        <ul ng-repeat="activeFilter in ActiveFilters">
            <li ng-model="activeFilter.checked" ng-click="removeFilter(ModifyFilter(activeFilter.checked,activeFilter))">{{activeFilter.name}}</li>
        </ul>
    </div>

</body>
```

Updated script:

```
var app = angular.module("DemoApp", [])

app.controller("DashboardCtrl", function($scope) {

    $scope.clearFilters = function() {
        angular.forEach($scope.Filters[0].filters, function(filter) {
          filter.checked = false;
        });
        $scope.ActiveFilters = [];
    };

    $scope.IsChecked = false;
    $scope.ActiveFilters = [];

    $scope.ModifyFilter = function (IsChecked, Filter) {
        console.log(IsChecked);
      if (IsChecked) {
        $scope.ActiveFilters.push(Filter);
      }
      else {
        var indexz = $scope.ActiveFilters.indexOf(Filter);
        $scope.ActiveFilters.splice(indexz, 1);
      }
    };


    $scope.Filters = 
         [
        {
            "title": "Equipment",
            "filters": [
                { name: "Rope", checked: false },
                { name: "Cables", checked: false },
                { name: "Dowel", checked: false },
                { name: "Ball", checked: false }
            ]
        }
    ];  
});
```

Look into my solution on js fiddle: [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z5sba90g/5/)

Comment: I have a bug or stack overflow have worst UI. I can't post link in proper way. kopy this from []

Comment: It does not allow the filters to be removed on click. https://jsfiddle.net/z5sba90g/4/ see here for it using buttons.